# KeyDown Event Runs Only When I Arrow Into a Field, Not when I Tab into or Enter Key Into the Field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've searched and can't find any help with this behavior. (I'm working in Access 2010, but the database is in Access 2000 file format.) I'm working with a form in datasheet view. I wrote the code below to copy Inventory Location from the record above if the Down Arrow key is pressed. The code works fine if I use the Down Arrow key to move vertically down from one record to the next, but not if I use the Tab or Enter keys to move from one field to the next.

```
Private Sub InventoryLocation_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    ' Variables are defined as Public at head of module.
    If KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then
        If Me.CurrentRecord = intPreviousRecordNumber + 1 Then
            If IsNull(Me.InventoryLocation.Value) Then
                Me.InventoryLocation.Value = varPreviousInventoryLocation
                DoCmd.CancelEvent
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Variable are being populated from the previous record here:

```
Private Sub InventoryLocation_LostFocus()
    ' Variables are defined as Public at head of module.
    varPreviousInventoryLocation = Me.InventoryLocation.Value
    intPreviousRecordNumber = Me.CurrentRecord
End Sub
```

This is my first post, but I find most of my answers here at StackOverflow.com. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you do what you want from that control's *On Got Focus* event?

Comment: I chose to use On Key Down, because I need to allow my user to decide when to copy the Inventory Location.

Comment: However, I just solved the problem. I've been struggling with this for three days, and of course, as soon as I ask the question, I figure it out!
My mistake apparently is that I thought my variable intPreviousRecordNumber could be reused for more than one field in the record. (I also have a field called OverstockLocation whose LostFocus event was setting the value of intPreviousRecordNumber. I assumed this was fine because the value would be the same for both fields in the same record.)

Comment: Apparently Access was objecting to both InventoryLocation and OverstockLocation trying to use the same variable.
I created a new variable called intPreviousRecordNumberOverstock, for use by the OverstockLocation code, and now both work as I expected.
I still don't know why though. I would have thought a row number variable could be used by one or more fields refering to that row number.
Thank you by the way, for your quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake apparently is that I thought my variable intPreviousRecordNumber could be used for more than one field in the record. (I also have a field called OverstockLocation whose LostFocus event was setting the value of intPreviousRecordNumber. I assumed this was fine because the value would be the same for both fields in the same record.)
Apparently Access was objecting to both InventoryLocation and OverstockLocation trying to use the same variable. I created a new variable called intPreviousRecordNumberOverstock, for use by the OverstockLocation code, and now both work as I expected.